# Omit certain bones from Automatic Weight calculations?

Tags: rigging, parent, vertex-weights

I have a foot rig I've prepared in advance, for use on various characters. It has some bones that are only IK target bones, so I don't want Automatic Weights to be calculated for those when I parent the mesh to the armature.

**How can I make Automatic Weights ignore *just* the bones that shouldn't deform the mesh?**

[image: Parenting a mesh with Automatic Weights]

Or if there is not a way to keep those bones from being included, what might an alternative solution be? Maybe there is something obvious I'm overlooking, because I would think this is not an uncommon situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, I found one way... Duplicate the armature and in the duplicate copy delete all bones that shouldn't deform the mesh. Parent the mesh to *this* armature using Auto Weights, then once weights have been generated delete the armature and replace it with the full (original) rig. Bone groups could be used to mark bones for deletion first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For bones that you don't want to deform the mesh, uncheck deform in the Deform Panel of bone properties.

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for. Knew there had to be a simple way. Thanks. :-)