# Is there a way to exclude bones needed only for a different mesh piece from auto-weighting for a given mesh?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm trying to rig a character's face where the armature contains teeth and lips bones. The former are not necessary for auto-(or manual-)weighting of the face skin mesh. Is it possible to exclude those bones from the face skin's auto-weight?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62138/omit-certain-bones-from-automatic-weight-calculations  Could select said bones Alt-click the checkbox to turn off before auto-weigthing said mesh, re-instate after.

Comment: That link has a two solutions presented that technically work, but are clunky. The first, presented by the author, is a hacky workaround that requires temporarily duplicating the whole armature, minus bones that have been deleted. The second solution, presented by another person, is to uncheck the Deform setting for the irrelevant bones after the fact. Neverrmind that when weight painting, one will still see this huge list of unnecessary vertex groups when choosing one to be painted, and so will need to sort through them to get to relevant ones. Vertex group filtering isn't the answer to this.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up figuring out to disable Deform (temporarily) on my own after making this question. Thanks for the alt-click tip though!